# OpenLayers 4 change position on load and input change

Tags: openlayers, position

I have map which should show position depends on input, which I control with switch. Long and Lat I am getting from API (depends on my input) which return to me coordinates. How can I show position from my coordinates? For me all time shows same position. Here is my code: Where am I wrong?

```
if(smth !='' && smth!=0){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'myApiUrl',
        data: {
            'region' : data_from switch,
            'my_key': 'my_key_here'
    },
        success: function(e){
            console.log(e);
            if(e.names.length > 0){

            center = ol.proj.transform([e.names[0].X, e.names[0].Y], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')


            var lonlat =ol.proj.transform([e.names[0].X,e.names[0].Y], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'); 
            var feature =  new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point([Math.floor(lonlat[0]),Math.floor(lonlat[1])]) 
                });
                    vectorLayer.getSource().addFeature(feature);
                    map.getView().setCenter(center);
                    map.getView().setZoom(14);

                console.log(lonlat);
                loadMarkers(e.names[0].X,e.names[0].Y);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Also I need to change position on change of same input, which will also use same switch and return coordinates. I have create crated function, which normally should show my position on change of input, it does not work also. Please help me to find mistake. Here is the code:

```
function loadMarkers(x, y){
    //console.log(x, y);
    var lonlat =ol.proj.transform([x,y], 'EPSG:4326',   'EPSG:3857'); 

    var feature =  new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([Math.floor(lonlat[0]),Math.floor(lonlat[1])]) 
    });

    vectorLayer.getSource().addFeature(feature);
    map.getView().setCenter(lonlat, 9);
}
```

This function I call on input change where inserting Long as 'Y' and Lat as 'X', but it does not show me anything also, also no errors.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE! Make sure to read the [tour] and try to focus on asking only one question per post.

Comment: You seem to obtained two accounts, which prevents you from editing. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts